# Fix Pyright error: Operator "in" not supported for types "Literal['Dispatch__'] and "_T@filter"

Tags: python-3.x, lint, pyright

I have a line of code that keeps getting flagged by Pyright and I'm not sure how I would rewrite this line of code:

```py
dispatch_vars = list(filter(lambda x: "Dispatch__" in x, df.columns))
```

And Pyright says:

```
[Pyright] Operator "in" not supported for types "Literal['Dispatch__']" and "_T@filter"
```

the code works as expected, so I'm not sure what it's trying to protect me against.

Comment: My best guess is that it is not treating your `Literal` as a `str`, but I can't reproduce this in the latest `pyright` (1.1.332).